# Deriving acceleration as function of time

Tags: game-physics

Okay, so I have this calculation describing a spring system, running each frame (~16ms, but not constant):

```
loop(deltaTime) {
  acceleration = (
    (-TENSION * (position - TARGET_POSITION)) + 
    (-FRICTION * velocity)
  ) / MASS

  velocity = velocity + acceleration * deltaTime
  position = position + velocity * deltaTime
}
```

All constant values are written in uppercase.

I want to calculate how far the spring described by the system overshoots it's `TARGET_POSITION`. I figured I should try to calculate at which point in time the velocity becomes 0 (marking reversal of the spring), then use this time value to calculate the position at that point.

I could just run my loop x times, until the velocity reversal happens, but that would be a rather brute force solution. I would rather derive a function which gives me the velocity at a given point in time. If I would have a function calculating acceleration as a function of time I think I can manage to derive to velocity function myself, but I got stuck because the formula contains the `position` en `velocity` of the previous frame, which I don't know how to eliminate.

How do I eliminate the current `position` and `velocity` when describing acceleration as a function of time?

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Suppose you have a function describing the acceleration of a body with respect to time and an initial velocity. You can compute the antiderivative of the acceleration function, add the initial velocity to it, and solve for a value of t for which the resulting expression is zero.

Comment: Yes, my thoughts exactly. But I'm struggling to find the initial function describing the acceleration of a body with respect to time. The loop described above is what I have to work with (external library), so I'm trying to somehow derive that function from the code. 

What throws me off is the lack of a variable t in the calculation of acceleration (acceleration is definitely not constant) and the occurence of position and velocity, which are the actual values at that point in time.

Comment: It looks like the function being described is `x''(t) = ((-T * (x(t) - P)) + (-F * x'(t)))/M`. This is a second order ODE, which you can solve using the relevant calculus. I didn't feel like doing that and just plugged it into Wolfram Alpha to get `x(t)` (which includes two constants representing the initial velocity and initial position). You can take as many derivatives of that as you like to get velocity/acceleration/jerk/etc as functions of time.

Comment: I just realized the notation in the comment above isn't super clear, `x''(t)`, `x'(t)` and `x(t)` represent acceleration, velocity, and displacement as functions of time respectively. A clearer way to write it is `x'' = (-T * (x - P) - F * x')/M`.

Comment: Your comment was clear, thanks! Didn't know Wolfram Alpha could do this stuff for you, that's incredible. Out of interest, what does ODE mean? I'd like to read up on how to solve this by hand.

Comment: It stands for "ordinary differential equation". The idea is that sometimes (in fact very often in real life), you have some function that is defined in terms of its own derivatives or integrals to various degrees. E.g. suppose we're interested in the acceleration at any moment in time of a mass attached to a spring that's been disturbed. The force the spring applies to the mass (and therefore the acceleration of the mass) is related to the displacement of the mass from the "resting" position. So we've got an equation relating the double derivative of displacement to the displacement, an ODE.

Comment: There are some really good notes I used to learn about this stuff a few years ago here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/DE.aspx if you're interested.